# algorithm for charge automatic matrix

Tags: vba, algorithm, factorial

I need algorithm to charge a matrix of `2^k` columns and `2^k` rows with a sign value of `-1` or `+1`. The first `k+1` columns will charge it but the rest (all combinations of `k` values) not.
I need to multiply all possibilities of `k` exp :
I have `k = 3` 
I need to multiply `1*2` and `1*3` and `2*3` and `1*2*3`. 
This is a simple example, but I need the general solution.
This method use for calculating `2^k` factorial design.

I tried the following code with visual basic but it did not work 100% (only the first (k+1) columns of the matrix are correct)

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
MSFlexGrid1.Cols = Text1.Text + 1
MSFlexGrid1.Rows = 3
MSFlexGrid1.Col = 0
MSFlexGrid1.Row = 1

MSFlexGrid1.Text = "Min"
MSFlexGrid1.Row = 2
MSFlexGrid1.Text = "Max"
For i = 1 To Text1.Text
MSFlexGrid1.Row = 0
MSFlexGrid1.Col = i
MSFlexGrid1.Text = "F" & Str(i)
Next i
End Sub
 Function FactFunct(ByVal M As Integer) As Integer
    Dim l As Integer
    l = 0
    For j = M - 1 To 1 Step -1
    l = l + j
    Next j
    FactFunct = l
 End Function
Private Sub Command2_Click()
Dim t As Integer

GR2.Visible = True
GR2.Cols = 2 ^ Val(Text1.Text) + 2
GR2.Rows = 2 ^ Val(Text1.Text) + 3
t = 1
GR2.Col = 1



'-------------------------- Incrementer les colonnes

For i = 1 To Val(Text1.Text) + 1
GR2.Row = 1

'-------------------------- declanchement de la routine
If i > 2 Then
t = t * 2
End If
c = -1
j = 1
l = 2 ^ Val(Text1.Text)

'-------------------------- Incrementer les lignes
Do While j <= l

        '-------------------------- chargement de la colonne 1
        If GR2.Col = 1 Then
        GR2.Text = 1
        GR2.Row = GR2.Row + 1
        j = j + 1
        Else

        b = 1

        '-------------------------- Incrementer les colonnes
        Do While b <= t
        GR2.Text = 1 * c

        GR2.Row = GR2.Row + 1


        b = b + 1
        j = j + 1
        Loop


        c = c * -1



        End If



   Loop


GR2.Col = GR2.Col + 1

Next i




'-----------------------------produit des colonnes
GR2.Col = Val(Text1.Text) + 1
Dim n, Puissance, PositionText, Nbrboucle, NbrValPro, ValColFix, PosCol As Integer
GridRout.Cols = Val(Text1.Text) - 1
Dim JJ As Integer
JJ = 0

For p = Val(Text1.Text) To 2 Step -1



GridRout.Col = JJ
GridRout.Text = FactFunct(p)
JJ = JJ + 1
Next p

For nbrrow = 1 To 2 ^ Val(Text1.Text)

routine = 2
charg = Val(Text1.Text) + 2

For i = 1 To 2

For j = 2 To Val(Text1.Text) + 1


res = 1
k = j

Do While i < routine

GR2.Row = nbrrow
GR2.Col = k
res = Val(res) * Val(GR2.Text)

k = k + 1
i = i + 1

If k = Val(Text1.Text) + 1 Then
k = j + 1

End If

Loop




For M = j + 1 To Val(Text1.Text) + 1

GR2.Row = nbrrow
GR2.Col = M

res2 = Val(res) * Val(GR2.Text)

GR2.Col = charg
GR2.Text = Val(res2)

charg = charg + 1

Next M



Next j

routine = routine + 1

Next i

Next nbrrow






End Sub
Private Sub Form_Load()
'GR2.Visible = False
'GridRout.Visible = False

End Sub


Private Sub MSFlexGrid1_DblClick()
MSFlexGrid1.Text = InputBox("give a number")
End Sub

Private Sub MSFlexGrid2_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: i use visual basic language , 100 % it mean the first (k+1) column of matrix is correct but the rest is not correct

Comment: If you have additional information, please edit your question. Don't write a comment, that most people will not see.

Comment: We would like to help, but it is very hard to understand how your code relates to what you asked. What is the output of this algorithm? We can't see what's your input and expected output.